# How to have two variables in one regex?

Tags: python, regex

How can I get two variables into one regular expression?

So far:

```
var1 = "Taco"
x = re.findall('(?<=\|)%s\|(?=\|)' % var1, string)
```

This works great for the one variable but I need to have something like:

```
x = re.findall('(?<=\|)%s\|%s(?=\|)' % var1 % var2, string)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = re.findall('(?<=\|)%s\|%s(?=\|)' % (var1, var2), string)
```

Comment: `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

Comment: Typo. Corrected. It works. You don't have to mark these things down when people are trying to help you.

Comment: You should be using new string formatting. `re.findall(r'(?<=\|){}\|{}(?=\|)'.format(var1, var2), string)`